# Arranging or ordering v-flex components using Vuetify

Tags: flexbox, vuetify.js

[image: flexbox problem]

As per the image above, I'm having trouble stacking or ordering my v-flex components the way that I need in my grid. Basically, I need my third v-flex (v-flex 3) to stack on the right side when the screen size changes to md.

I've been messing around with this for a few hours, and I am stuck. I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can achieve your desired results:

```
<v-layout row wrap justify-center>

    <v-flex md6><v-btn block dark>1</v-btn></v-flex>
    <v-flex md6><v-btn block dark>2</v-btn></v-flex>
    <v-flex xs12 md6 order-md2><v-btn block dark>3</v-btn></v-flex>
    <v-flex xs10 md6 order-md1><v-btn block dark>4</v-btn></v-flex>

</v-layout>
```

You can learn more about it [Here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid).

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/aMRmMM?&editable=true&editors=101) that does that.

By adding `justify-center` you make sure that when your `v-flex` does not get the entire row, it will still look nice(in this case, in the center). You can also control the ordering of grid items by using `order-{screenBreakpoint}{order}` so in this case I used `order-md2` for `3rd v-flex` and `order-md1` for `4th v-flex`.

The order in medium size screen:

[image: The order in medium size screen]

The order in smaller size screen:

[image: The order in smaller size screen]

Comment: The problem is that I need 3 to be right under 2 on the right side, as can be seen in this codepen example https://codepen.io/mr--brown/pen/aMRmoY

Comment: I added the screenshot so you can see how it works and your Codepen does not show anything but error @user1819087

Comment: @user1819087 if you do not know how to add a Codepen please see this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343422/codepen-link-and-snippets). I have also added my Codepen as well in the answer

Comment: @user1819087 I think there is a problem with your logic. On md screen-size in-order for 2nd and 3rd v-flex to fit at the right side of the 1st v-flex, they need to be in one column and in order for them to fit horizontally they need to be in one row. So, on smaller screen-size your changes on 3rd v-flex will also apply to the 2nd one, unless you show them vertically not horizontally. I have created another Codepen that "almost" does what you are looking for.

Comment: @user1819087 sorry I forgot to give the link to it [Here](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/rRqGKX)